# NetBeans 8.1 Remote Connections SFTP Error: Connection closed by foreign host

Tags: netbeans, proxy, sftp, remote-connections

I'm developing a website on a server using NetBean's HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript and PHP support. I am trying to set up the remote connection so I don't have to use something like Filezilla every time to transfer my files to the server. However, NetBeans is unable to connect to my server over SFTP.

I'm unable to share screenshots with the actual information because this is for work and must be kept confidential.

[image: Remote Connections]

**Host Name** is in the form: ***subdomain.domain.com***

**Username** is just the plain username, it's NOT in the form ***username@subdomain.domain.com***.

I am using a **password**, not a key.

I am behind my work's proxy but I don't think that could be the cause because NetBeans connecting to my server is the only thing that isn't working.
Filezilla works, Putty (SSH) works, Aptana remote connections (SFTP) works, all my browsers work. Even testing the proxy settings in the NetBeans general options works in NetBeans:

[image]

Anyway...

After entering in all of the server's information, I click "Test Connection". After 30 seconds (the timeout), this error pops up:

[image]

I tried looking in the NetBeans log to gather more information but it doesn't appear to be logging this error. Is there a certain debug flag I need to enable?

Like I said earlier, Filezilla and Aptana Studio can both connect to my server using the same login credentials.

Any suggestions?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: are you doing key or password?

Comment: I'm using a password. (I've updated my post)

Comment: Can you see server logs when you attempt this?

Comment: SFTP server logs aren't enabled and I'd prefer not to bother the sysadmin to enable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my system proxy settings (which were configured for my work's proxy) were preventing me from connecting to a server on my work's local intranet.

I had to add a proxy exception for the server and everything worked after that.